# Sorting "human readable" file sizes

Tags: bash, sort, array

How do we sort by using any Linux core utility (scripts) numerical value of output of du such as:

```
136K    foo.bar/feed
140K    foo.bar/buy-electronic-components
32K foo.bar/cdn-cgi
88K foo.bar/what-is-ground
344K    foo.bar/ldr-circuit-diagram
64K foo.bar/what-is-an-led
100K    foo.bar/types-of-resistors
516K    foo.bar/wp-includes
60K  foo.bar/author
56K  foo.bar/diy-pcb
112K    foo.bar/how-to-learn-electronics
376K    foo.bar/category
76K  foo.bar/electronic-schematics
84K  foo.bar/how-to-bar
88K foo.bar/bar-tools
20K foo.bar/comments
88K foo.bar/right-bar-temperature
48K foo.bar/contact
44K foo.bar/products
80K foo.bar/types-of-bar
3M foo.bar/
3M total
```

if in descending way to be:

```
3M foo.bar/
3M total
516K    foo.bar/wp-includes
376K    foo.bar/category
344K    foo.bar/ldr-circuit-diagram
140K    foo.bar/buy-electronic-components
...
```

Thank you much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` has an option `--human-numeric-sort` and `--sort=human-numeric` to do exactly this.

Comment: BTW the short option for `--human-numeric-sort` is `-h`